# Android deep linking and launchmode

Tags: android, deep-linking, bottomnavigationview

I have single activity app with bottom navigation to which I have added deeplinks. The deeplink is to a fragment inside the navgraph. I pass some data with this deeplink which is then processed further.

When I open the deeplink from whatsapp and the app is closed, the link works fine. It redirects to the correct fragment.

I have added the nav-graph to the MainActivity

```
<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/fragment"/>
```

But when the app is open and I tap the link in whatsapp, the app comes to foreground, but the deeplink doesn't work. Not even the correct fragment will load.

I have tried changing android:launchMode="singleTask" to "singleTop", but then the app opens inside whatsapp.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. My activity launchMode is still singleTask.

So in my MainActivity, I have over ridden the following:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent( intent );
    super.onNewIntent( intent );
}
```

I can then call `getIntent()` in `onResume()` and play perform the remainder of the task.

`onNewIntent` is only an entry point into the app when it is in the background. So all processing and UI changes will have to be handled via `onResume`.

Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong or if you have a better method.